# Can I use Java Spark Framework to create regular War for deploying in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spark-java, j2html

I have happily used [Java Spark Framework](http://sparkjava.com) (& [j2html](https://j2html.com/)) as part of a standard Java application to provide a browser based UI, this has worked very well.

I would now like to build my website using the same technology instead of using Servlet/Jsps as I am currently. But the difference is that the website runs on AWS within a Tomcat container and Im not sure if Java Spark can be used to create a web archive (.war) file so I can continue to deploy it in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not difficult.

From their [documentation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation#other-web-server):

1. You need to change your main class and implement `spark.servlet.SparkApplication`
2. Add the specified filter to your web.xml changing `<param-value>com.company.YourApplication</param-value>` with the name of your class.
3. Move your routes to the init method of your main class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou , missed that

Comment: sure thing.I was just waiting for any other replies but none seem to be forthcoming